# Convert datetime to UniversalDateTime UTC

Tags: c#, datetime, utc

I have one dateTime `'1/14/2015 10:00 AM'` and variable with zimeZone in this format "-0500" 
when I convert to UniversalTime, the DateTime is converted depending on server location, how I can to parse this dateTime to UniversalTime using my variable with this format of values: `"-0200"`, "`+0300`" , "`-0600`" etc

EDIT:
Now I use this code:

```
            var timeZone = "+0200";
            var hoursDif = timeZone.ToString().Substring(0,3);
            var minDif = timeZone.ToString().Substring(3, 2);

            var TimeSpatFromZone = new TimeSpan(Convert.ToInt32(hoursDif), Convert.ToInt32(minDif), 0);
            DateTime convertedStart = DateTime.Parse("1/14/2015 10:00 AM");
            var datetimeUTC = new DateTime();

            datetimeUTC = convertedStart + TimeSpatFromZone;
            Console.WriteLine(datetimeUTC);
```

Comment: I don't understand. What do you want as a result exactly? What is your current time zone offset?

Comment: And what does your current code look like? I'd recommend using `DateTimeOffset` by the way, as that represents the exact information you actually have.

Comment: Please improve  your question. Most people does not have time to guess what you really want. Says what is  your input what is your expected output that you are not able to get etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can get your offsets into an HH:MM format you can use the DateTimeOffset.ParseExact function. This will do the trick:

```
String properOffset = myOffset.Insert(3, ":"); // -0500 becomes -05:00
```

For the whole "date with offset" string, use this:

```
String dateToConvert = myDate + " " + myOffset.Insert(3, ":");
```

This will change `1/14/2015 10:00 AM` and `-0500` to `1/14/2015 10:00 AM -05:00`. Then call `ParseExact`:

```
DateTimeOffset myDTO = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(
  dateToConvert,
  "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt zzz",
  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` is for a format provider, and because you're using `/` and `:` as date and time delimiters the "invariant" culture will work fine here.

The format strings are explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx). `DateTimeOffset` is covered [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343428%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: _The null is for a format provider, which you don't need here_ Actually it _needs_ an `IFormatProvider` which has `/` as a `DateSeparator`. Otherwise, it throws `FormatException`.

Comment: Thanks @SonerGönül - you're correct. I've gotten away plenty with leaving it null, but it's better to specify one. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime.Parse(v=vs.110).aspx#StringToParse

> A string that includes the date and time along with time zone offset information; for example:
>
> 03/01/2009 05:42:00 -5:00

Given the string `1/13/2015 10:00 AM` and offset `-0200` you can simply combine the two to create a string that can be passed to the `DateTime.Parse()` method.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
Convert.ToDateTime("dfsdf").ToUniversalTime();
```